# How do I read files from an string array of file names?

Tags: c, arrays, file, unix, directory

So im writing a program to open a directory, get all the files inside, and then read the contents of each file. currently i successfully got all the file names in a string array. the print files[] loop shows all the file names, but the loop to check frequency does not read the files correctly. how do i successfully read an array of file names and then scan each of their contents?

```
//Open Directory
        DIR *dr = opendir(path);
        struct dirent *de;
        if(dr == NULL){
                printf("Could not open directory");
                return 0 ;
        }
        const char* files[100];
        int buffer=0;
        //Read Directory Files
        while((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL){
                files[buffer] = de->d_name;
                buffer++;
        }
        for(int x = 0; x <= buffer; x++){
                printf("%s" , files[x]);
        }
        closedir(dr);
        //Check Frequency
        for(int i = 0; i <= buffer; i++){
                int ch;
                FILE *fp;
                fp = fopen(files[i], "r");
                if(fp == NULL)
                        continue;
                ch = fgetc(fp);
                while(ch != EOF){
                        ch = tolower(ch);
                        if(ch>=97 && ch<= 122){
                                alphabetfreq[ch-97]++;
                        }
                        ch = fgetc(fp);
                }
        fclose(fp);
```

Comment: The problem seems to be in the "Check Frequency" loop

Comment: You cannot simply assign the pointer from `de->d_name` to your array. `de->d_name` is an internal variable and likely reused by `readdir`. You should allocate for each name and store the name instead of a pointer to `de->d_name`

Comment: You may want to look at [C writing readdir to char array variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51804567/c-writing-readdir-to-char-array-variable/51804959?r=SearchResults&s=1|54.9089#51804959)

Comment: `alphabetfreq[]` definition and much else missing.  Review [mcve]

Comment: The posted code is missing the check for a sub directory.  The posted code is missing the check for  `.` and `..` file names.   The posted code is missing the check for symbolic links

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things wrong with the program. But the main reason why it is not reading the files is that you are just passing the file names to fopen(), so it is looking for them in current directory and returning null values. Also you are not handling the null results carefully. And the condition in the loop should x < buffer and not x <= buffer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
  int alphabetfreq[100], i;
  for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    alphabetfreq[i] = 0;
  }
  char path[] =  "/home/path_to_directory/";
  DIR *dr = opendir(path);
       struct dirent *de;
       if(dr == NULL){
               printf("Could not open directory");
               return 0 ;
       }
       const char* files[100];
       int buffer=0;
       //Read Directory Files
       while((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL){
               files[buffer] = de->d_name;
               buffer++;
       }
       for(int x = 0; x < buffer; x++){
               printf("%s" , files[x]);
       }
       closedir(dr);
       printf("\n");
       //Check Frequency
       for(int i = 0; i < buffer; i++){
               int ch;
               FILE *fp;
               char * file = malloc(strlen(path) + strlen(files[i]) + 1);
               strcpy(file, path);
               strcat(file, files[i]);
               fp = fopen(file, "r");
               if(fp == NULL)
              {
                printf("no file %s\n", file);
                continue;
              }
               ch = fgetc(fp);
               while(ch != EOF){
                       ch = tolower(ch);
                       if(ch>=97 && ch<= 122){
                               alphabetfreq[ch-97]++;
                       }
                       ch = fgetc(fp);
               }

       fclose(fp);
     }

     for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
     {
       printf("%c %d\n", i+97, alphabetfreq[i]);
     }
}
```

This is working for me.

Comment: `files[buffer] = de->d_name;` suffers from the same problem noted in the comments under the original question.

Comment: Additionally the number of file names is hard coded; there might be more than 100 files. And why not allocate the space for each filename including the path in the loop reading the directory? Your source doesn't free the memory, anyway.

Comment: I think it is okay to copy pointer value from `de->d_name` because we only need to read it(at least in this case). The better option would be creating a pointer array of `de` type and store the return values there.